# JQuery - $.ajax - Firefox 10 running ahead of itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a simple $.ajax POST call for an XML file to populate HTML elements. It's working fine in IE 9. The "error:" clause works fine in both browsers. In the "success:" case, IE 9 waits politely at point A: for the "success:" clause to complete. Eager-beaver FF 10 barges on in what looks for all the world like a separate thread, returns to the calling "doPopulate()" function before the "design_xml" variable is up and running, and consequently fails to load the HTML element.

But if I make it wait with the window.alert in the final line this gets it working right - apparently providing a pause to let the $.ajax call catch up. Now I don't want an alert just here, so I've tried various delay-loops - timeout, for-loop, etc. - but none of them work. Can anybody tell me what's happening here?

URLs are local machine. Windows Vista.

```
var design_xml = null; //Global variable to hold design XML
var template_url = "Docs_and_notes/Design_template_02.xml";  //Template URL (temp loc.)
var template_urlzz = "Docs_and_notes/zzDesign_template_02.xml";  // Duff template URL for testing

function getDefaults() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: template_url,
    timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds or go home
    success: function(xml) {
console.log("Succeed");
        design_xml = xml; xml = null;  //Make XML global, kill original 
    },
    error: function(request, status, err) { //Catch misfires
console.log("Fail");        
        window.alert("Error 001: Design template not loaded. Status: " + status + " err:" + err);   
    }
//Point A:      
    //window.alert("Final line");   
    }); 

function doPopulate() {
    getDefaults();
    $("#fn").text($('filename', design_xml).text());
}
```

XML:

```
<filename default="untitled">gaberlunzie</filename>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="doPopulate()"></button>
    <div>
        <span id="fn">Filename</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: AJAX expands to _Asynchronous_ JavaScript and XML, and you are expecting the request to be synchronous. It's not "running ahead", it's just how it is supposed to work.

Comment: questions should really be why is IE so slow that the operation completes before it even gets to that part.

Comment: Including "async:false" doesn't seem to make any difference. I'm feeling my way here, chewing the gristle, so I'll play with it some more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The line `$("#fn").text($('filename', design_xml).text());` should be in the `success` parameter, after you set `design_xml`.

Comment: or even just use the xml passed into success, no need for global design_xml unless they're using it somewhere else

Comment: bdares, thanks - I think that will solve it - there's a little downstream code before it stops for user input events, so I'll need to check that out, but I think that will get me over the hump. Thank you. Dampsquid - it forms the document for the user, so design_xml needs to be global. Thanks.